# AS replace all with or condition

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to do a replace with two characters.

Below is my code, my problem is now i need to replace '/' as well rather than just '-', run replace twice is not really a good idea, and i am pretty bad at regular expression. Is anyone can help me write a RegExp which will search the whole string and replace any '-' o r'/' have.

```
var myPattern:RegExp = / /gi;
productId.replace(myPattern, '-')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match any character within `[]` of your RegEx.

To replace both "/" and " " (space):

```
replace(/[\/ ]/g, "-");
```

Example:

```
var s:String = "2012/10/29 12:29";
trace(s.replace(/[\/ ]/g, "-"));
```

Would produce:

> 2012-10-29-12:29

Answer (score 1):

this should replace any '**/**' or '**-**' in your productId string to a '**$**'

```
var myPattern:RegExp = /[\/-]/g;
productId.replace(myPattern, '$');
```